# Replacing an html table with a div tag

Tags: html, css

I have an html table on my website (emma-moore.com) that I'm using for layout instead of tabular data:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="5px" width="100%" class="followFont">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Follow your heart</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding-bottom: 10px">and you'll always</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">
        <img border="0" src="balloonsAndLavenderFields.jpg" width="99px" height="150px" class="homePictureFrame" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" style="padding-top: 10px">end up where your</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">soul needs to be.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Best practice is not to use inline styles and tables for layout, and I'm wondering how to replace the table with a div block and put the text and the jpg inside the div block in such a way that the text and jpg display the same way as they do when using the table. How can I best do this with css and a div block?

Thanks,

William

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pgpjbb6x/1/ play with margins/paddings to get desired result...

Comment: you should validate your html and css, for example you have <!DOCTYPE html> in the first line, then line 49 you have  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  that is completely wrong. check out https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.emma-moore.com%2F

Comment: Thanks, guys. And that is an elegant solution, nevermind. Do all the tags in the div block inherit the 5px padding?

Comment: no, just the element that class is applied to if you want to all the containing div's of the class the css would be: `.followFont div {padding:5px;}`. BTW, your website fails if you go to emma-moore.com without putting www as the subdomain, you should look into an alias for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div id="table" style="display: table;">
    <div class="cell" id="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="cell2"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="cell3"></div>
</div>
```

You'll be using like table
Div can have the same properties as table

like

```
#table
{
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center:
   border:solid 1px #ddd;
   width:100%;
}
.cell
{
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
   text-align:center;
   border:solid 1px #ddd;
   width:25%;
   padding:10px;
}
```

and soon....
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
.followFont 
{
padding:5px;
border:0;
cellpadding:5px;
width:100%;
display:table; 
}

<div class="followFont">

<div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="width:100%; display:table-cell; text-align:left;">Follow your heart</div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="width:100%; display:table-cell; text-align:left; padding-bottom: 10px;">and you'll always</div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="width:100%; display:table-cell; text-align:left;">
        <img border="0" src="balloonsAndLavenderFields.jpg" width="99px" height="150px" class="homePictureFrame" />
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="width:100%; display:table-cell; text-align:left; padding-top: 10px;">end up where your</div>
</div>

<div style="display:table-row;">
    <div style="width:100%; display:table-cell; text-align:left;">
      soul needs to be.
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Link:-https://html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/

```
<h2>Phone numbers</h2>
    <table width="300" border="1" cellpadding="5" style="text-align: center">
    <tr>
    <th width="75"><strong>Name</strong></th>
    <th><span style="font-weight: bold;">Telephone</span></th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td><a href="tel:0123456785">0123 456 785</a></td>
    <td><img src="images/check.gif" alt="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cassie</td>
    <td><a href="tel:9876532432">9876 532 432</a></td>
    <td><img src="images/check.gif" alt="checked" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

---

```
<h2>Phone numbers</h2>
<div class="rTable">
<div class="rTableRow">
<div class="rTableHead"><strong>Name</strong></div>
<div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Telephone</span></div>
<div class="rTableHead">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="rTableRow">
<div class="rTableCell">John</div>
<div class="rTableCell"><a href="tel:0123456785">0123 456 785</a></div>
<div class="rTableCell"><img src="images/check.gif" alt="checked" /></div>
</div>
<div class="rTableRow">
<div class="rTableCell">Cassie</div>
<div class="rTableCell"><a href="tel:9876532432">9876 532 432</a></div>
<div class="rTableCell"><img src="images/check.gif" alt="checked" /></div>
</div>
</div>
```